# Use Unity Handles for interaction in the scene view

Tags: unity, gui

I want to give an object with a specific script arrows to do special functions in the scene view. I have gotten Unity to render the arrows but I have no idea how to actually handle mouse events. [The docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.ArrowHandleCap.html) appear to say that I should be able to identify what receives a mouse down event by calling `HandleUtility.nearestControl` however when clicking on different arrows in the scene view I get the same ControlId (which i'm guessing is the gameobject itself). How are you supposed to know/deal with mouse events properly?

[image]

Code:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Script))]
class SceneGui : UnityEditor.Editor
{
    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
        {
            Transform transform = ((Script)target).transform;
            {
                Vector3 pos = transform.position + Vector3.left * 2;
                Handles.color = Color.yellow;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(3000, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.left),
                    2, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = transform.position + Vector3.right * 2;
                Handles.color = Color.red;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(3001, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.right),
                    2, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = transform.position + Vector3.forward * 2;
                Handles.color = Color.blue;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(3002, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward),
                    2, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = transform.position + Vector3.back * 2;
                Handles.color = Color.cyan;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(3003, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.back),
                    2, EventType.Repaint);
            }
        }
        else if (Event.current.type == EventType.mouseDown)
        {
            Debug.Log(HandleUtility.nearestControl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need to call the `Handles.ArrowHandleCap` function with the `EventType.Layout` in the relevant `Event.current` slot. So with that you call the same function again and that will do all of the click calculations for you.

For the control ID you should also use `GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive)` as that will give you a temporary id that is valid and won't clash with other stuff.

[image]

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Script))]
class SceneGui : UnityEditor.Editor
{
    private const int arrowSize = 2;
    private const float CenterOffset = 3f;

    private int leftId, rightId, forwardId, backId;
    private Transform trans;
    private bool cached = false;

    private Direction selectedDirection = Direction.none;

    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        if (!cached)
        {
            trans = ((Script)target).transform;

            leftId = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);
            rightId = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);
            forwardId = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);
            backId = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);

            cached = true;
        }


        if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
        {
            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.left * CenterOffset;
                Handles.color = selectedDirection == Direction.west ? Color.magenta : Color.yellow;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(leftId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.left), arrowSize, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.right * CenterOffset;
                Handles.color = selectedDirection == Direction.east ? Color.magenta : Color.red;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(rightId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.right), arrowSize, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.forward * CenterOffset;
                Handles.color = selectedDirection == Direction.north ? Color.magenta : Color.blue;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(forwardId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward), arrowSize, EventType.Repaint);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.back * CenterOffset;
                Handles.color = selectedDirection == Direction.south ? Color.magenta : Color.cyan;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(backId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.back), arrowSize, EventType.Repaint);
            }
        }
        else if (Event.current.type == EventType.layout)
        {
            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.left * CenterOffset;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(leftId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.left), arrowSize, EventType.layout);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.right * CenterOffset;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(rightId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.right), arrowSize, EventType.layout);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.forward * CenterOffset;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(forwardId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward), arrowSize, EventType.layout);
            }

            {
                Vector3 pos = trans.position + Vector3.back * CenterOffset;
                Handles.ArrowHandleCap(backId, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.back), arrowSize, EventType.layout);
            }
        }
        else if (Event.current.type == EventType.mouseDown)
        {
            int id = HandleUtility.nearestControl;

            if (id == leftId) selectedDirection = Direction.west;
            else if (id == rightId) selectedDirection = Direction.east;
            else if (id == forwardId) selectedDirection = Direction.north;
            else if (id == backId) selectedDirection = Direction.south;
            else selectedDirection = Direction.none;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

For anyone that wants to use this code while running the code in this answer my Unity decided to have a heart attack and died. After restarting it the behaviour of this was different. It stopped redrawing while the mouse was moving so I had to add a small line to redraw the editor script while the mouse is moving! see [`HandleUtility.Repaint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HandleUtility.Repaint.html).